# Is there a name for doing a running total that is actually just the total of subsets?

Tags: terminology

There's a concept I've used frequently where I create an O(n) operation for finding the sum of all subsets a<sub>*i*</sub>...a<sub>*i*+*L*</sub> where L is the length of a subset.

> *i* ← 0
>   *j* ← *i* - length of subsets
>   *subsetTotal* ← 0
>
> **while** *i* < length of *a*
>     *subsetTotal* ← *subsetTotal* + *a<sub>i</sub>*
>
> **if** *j* ≥ 0
>       Save *subsetTotal* to a collection
>       *subsetTotal* ← *subsetTotal* - *a<sub>j</sub>*
>
> *i* ← *i* + 1
>     *j* ← *j* + 1

I know that using a O(n) loop to find the total of an entire set is known as a "running total," but what do you call that total for an O(n) operation finding the sums of subsets?

What is the term for `subsetTotal` in the above psuedocode?

Comment: I've been going with the term "rolling total" since I picture it like a ball rolling over the set, but googling that term only comes up with references to the term "running total."

Comment: What do you mean by "the sum of all subsets"?  What does it mean to take the sum of multiple sets?  I know what it means to take the sum of several numbers, but not the sum of several sets.  Why do you need a "name" for this?  What will you do with the name?  Usually instead of asking for a "name", it's better to figure out how you plan to use the name, then ask about what you're actually trying to accomplish.  That way, you have two ways to win: either someone gives you a name for it, or they show you how to accomplish what you really want (even if there is no standard "name" for it).

Comment: I included to psuedocode to make it as clear as I possibly could. Not knowing the proper terminology is exactly why I'm asking the question. The only thing I want to accomplish by it is to have a term to use when referring to this technique while discussing an algorithm in plain English.